# Check values in file is greater or equal in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have file.txt include:

`2
10
60
90`

now how can i check if numbers in that file is equal on greater than 50 end then do something. Something in my case is sending an email this part i have.
I have tried do this with awk but it does not work in script.

Comment: Show us your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will output the greatest value of your file:

```
sort -nr file.txt | head -1
```

Then just compare it to the value of your choice and voilà. Something like:

```
if [ `sort -nr file.txt | head -1` -ge 50 ]
then
  <do something>
fi
```

Explanation:

`sort -n` sorts the file as numbers (otherwise 12 would be considered greater than 100).

`sort -r` reverse the sort (by default it displays lower numbers first, with `-r` it displays higher first).

`head -1` displays only the first output.

Comment: Someone’s got some nerve to downvote an answer without explaining what’s wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

This will serve your job.

```
$ awk 'FNR > 0 { if($1 > 50) print $1 }' <file>
```